# Linking interdependent, static C and Fortran libraries with CMake?

Tags: c, cmake, fortran

I am new to CMake, and have a (legacy) package with a C main program that links (interdependent) C and Fortran libraries. The main program source is in the top-level directory, the C library source is in a sub-directory of the top-level directory, and the Fortran library source is in another (peer) sub-directory. Oversimplified, it looks like:

```
+-- main.c
+-- mmf
|   +-- (C source)
+-- prms
    +-- (Fortran source)
```

I have one `CMakeLists.txt` file in each directory, for a total of three. They are [here](https://github.com/ashalper-usgs/prms/blob/5.1/CMakeLists.txt), [here](https://github.com/ashalper-usgs/prms/blob/5.1/mmf/CMakeLists.txt), and [here](https://github.com/ashalper-usgs/prms/blob/5.1/prms/CMakeLists.txt).

Everything appears to work well until the final linking stage, when:

```
[100%] Linking C executable PRMS
/usr/bin/ld: prms/libprms.a(ccsolrad.f90.o): in function `ccsolrad_':
ccsolrad.f90:(.text+0xbe0): undefined reference to `declvar_'
/usr/bin/ld: ccsolrad.f90:(.text+0xc4b): undefined reference to `declvar_'
/usr/bin/ld: ccsolrad.f90:(.text+0xe1d): undefined reference to `declvar_'
/usr/bin/ld: ccsolrad.f90:(.text+0xe88): undefined reference to `declvar_'
```

which is some Fortran code in the Fortran library attempting to link with a Fortran-to-C adapter function in the C library.

Would anyone have ideas on how to do this correctly?

Thanks very much!

Comment: Show the linking command. Rerun make with `VERBOSE=1`.

Comment: ```[100%] Linking C executable PRMS
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/PRMS.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/cc   -rdynamic CMakeFiles/PRMS.dir/main.c.o  -o PRMS mmf/libmmf.a -lm prms/libprms.a -lgfortran -lgfortran -lm -lquadmath -lm 
/usr/bin/ld: prms/libprms.a(ccsolrad.f90.o): in function `ccsolrad_':
ccsolrad.f90:(.text+0xbe0): undefined reference to `declvar_'
/usr/bin/ld: ccsolrad.f90:(.text+0xc4b): undefined reference to `declvar_'```

Comment: Maybe I am not right. What if you would link with the libraries twice `target_link_libraries(PRMS mmf m prms gfortran  mmf m prms gfortran)` ? Also you can check that `libmmf.a` really has `declvar_` symbol.

Comment: For the future: On Stack Overflow we want the **code** to be **in the question post** itself, not *linked*. Among other things, this allows the question to remain a valid even after linked code has been changed (as in your case, when the current code corresponds to the fixed problem) or even deleted.

Answer (score 1):

The library `prms` uses symbols exported by `mmf`. You need to link `prms` with `mmf`.

Add:

```
target_link_libraries(prms PUBLIC mmf)
```

to [this](https://github.com/ashalper-usgs/prms/blob/5.1/prms/CMakeLists.txt).

Comment: Excellent! That was it. Thanks Kamil!